# Is Randall-Sundrum model background independent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, string-theory, ads-cft, branes, holographic-principle

Randall-Sundrum model (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randall%E2%80%93Sundrum_model) is related on string theory.

String theory can be background independent (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_independence):

> String theory is usually formulated with perturbation theory around a fixed background. While it is possible that the theory defined this way is locally background-invariant, if so, it is not manifest, and it is not clear what the exact meaning is. One attempt to formulate string theory in a manifestly background-independent fashion is string field theory, but little progress has been made in understanding it.
>   Another approach is the conjectured, but yet unproven AdS/CFT duality

Since some "types" of Randall-Sundrum models have been useful to understand AdS/CFT, can they be background independent as well?

Are there some "types" of Randall-Sundrum models which are completely based on string theory?

Also, are there any "types" of Randall-Sundrum models that are completely independent from string theory? That could possibly be right even if string theory is wrong?

And finally, can we build Randall-Sundrum models that can represent any type of theory/mathematical structure (similar to what happens with holographic principle)?

Comment: 1. The Randall-Sundrum model, being strictly five-dimensional and not derived from a 10d string theory, is *not* based on string theory. 2. What exactly do you *technically* mean by background-independence? (Discussions of "background independence" frequently get stuck because people use inequivalent technical notions of it, all allegedly being expressions of the colloquial notion)

Comment: @ACuriousMind Thank you for your comment. As to number 1: But there are some "types" of Randall-Sundrum models which are based on string theory isn't it? As to number 2: I would mean whether Randall-Sundrum models could be compatible with any type of spaces and number of dimensons. Maybe it is a vague question but I was wondering whether we could build Randall-Sundrum models that could represent/"produce" any type of theory. Any type of mathematical structure.